# How can I recover my PATH of mac

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, path

I just changed the PATH in .bash_profile and there must have been something wrong with that path, thus the `echo $PATH` shows `“/usr/local/Cellar/Anaconda2/bin:??` and when I try to open the .bash_profile and check it again with `open -e .bash_profile`, it shows `Trace/BPT trap: 5`. 
Wish you can help me deal with this problem!

Comment: You may wish to look at these questions - - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/113379 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/30461201/3395469

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset your PATH to the macOS default by pasting this into your Terminal window:

```
export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

That’ll get you access to the editors you’d normally use to edit your shell startup scripts. So you should be able to then fix the damage.